# Red language not compiling for Android

Tags: rebol, red

I have a small GUI program in Red language that runs very well but is not compiling for Android. I am using following command on Debian Stable Linux (which successfully makes applications for Windows and for Mac):

```
$ wine red-063.exe -c -r -t Android-x86 myapp.r
```

But I get following error messages:

```
Target: Android-x86 

Compiling to native code...
*** Warning: OS_TYPE macro in R/S is redefined
*** Compilation Error: invalid path value: image/encode 
*** in file: %environment/codecs/png.red 
*** in function: exec/ctx259~encode
*** at line: 1 
*** near: [as cell! image/encode img where IMAGE_PNG]
```

I get same error messages if I use `Android` instead of `Android-x86`. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GUI for Android is planned for [0.65](https://trello.com/b/FlQ6pzdB/red-tasks-overview)

Comment: It should be clarified on https://github.com/red/red  where Android and Android-x86 are listed.